# How can I directly compare the effects of a predictor on a continuous and a dichotomous dependent variable?

Tags: regression-coefficients, binary-data, effect-size, pseudo-r-squared, linear-probability-model

I want to **assess how a predictor differs in its associations with 2 different dependent measures** (i.e., a continuous measure of objective memory and a categorical measure of self-rated memory). I also have some covariates I want to control for (i.e., age and gender).

The initial idea was to run OLS regressions, predicting each memory measure from the predictor and controlling for the covariates. Then I wanted to compare the betas associated with each predictor of interest. However, while one of the dependent variables is continuous, the other one is dichotomous (i.e., a Yes/No response), and so modelling it with an OLS regression does not seem appropriate. I am not interested in correct prediction but more so in **comparing the direction, significance and size of the effect of the predictor on these 2 variables**. How can I do that?

Some of the options I have considered:

1. Converting my dichotomous dependent variable to a continuous and running a linear probability model. However, I am not sure how much I can trust the relative size of the effect of the predictor when comparing across models, see [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-014-0057-0).
2. Using a new goodness-of-fit measure called "surrogate R squared" (see [recent paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36250345/)] to calculate the change in R squared from the reduced model (i.e., `dichotomous_DV ~ age + gender`) to a full model (i.e., `dichotomous_DV ~ predictor + age + gender`) for the predictor. This seems to work fine to get the size of the effect, but I am not sure how to get the direction of the effect and its significance. Ideally, I would like to be able to also get a beta, SE, t-value and p-value for my predictor.
3. Combining the approaches 1 and 2 somehow?

Any ideas would be much appreciated!